# Remove Like button from Facebook Comments plugin (iFrame version)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are instructions on how to scrub the Like button from the Comments plugin for the XFBML version, but not the iFrame one. The Like button bundled with the Comments plugin is redundant since we already have a share bar.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version of the Facebook comments plugin would allow you to specify a custom css style sheet where you could remove this.  The newest second version of this plugin does not allow for this so you won't be able to modify, aside from shrinking the iframe that holds the comment box.

Comment: We just switched to use the Javascript version. Thanks. Simpler that way.